# Is there a way to make promise "mapping" inside async function (AWS DynamoDB SDK usecase example)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, promise, async-await, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have serverless app based on AWS Lambda and use async/await pattern for accessing all data from DynamoDB (and other async calls):

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const params = {
        TableName : "Items"
    };

    const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    const items = data.Items;

    // use items
  }
  catch(err) {
    // error handling
  }
}
```

Of course, to make things better I moved all such calls to functions like:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const data = await getItems();
    const items = data.Items;

    // use items
  }
  catch(err) {
    // error handling
  }
}

let getItems = async function() {
    let params = {
        TableName : "Items"
    };

    return await docClient.scan(params).promise();
};

// getFeatures(), writeObjects(), putAnything() implementations
```

The problem is evident - I have to know every time data format which depends on DB call type - it can be "data.Items" or "data.Item" etc. This breaks encapsulation. Is there any way like "map" Promise inside a function to return as result promise from "data.XXX" and not just from "data"? Desired result:

```
const items = await getItems();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with promises? After you `await`ed it, you have a plain value and can access arbitrary property names like always, e.g. `data[params.TableName]`.

Comment: Btw, `let getItems = async function() {` could be shortened to `async function getItems() {`

Comment: @Bergi unfortunatelly you haven't understood what is question about. It's not about possibility to perform field access after awaitng - natural that it's possible. It's about program design. Moving information about how the field should be accessed out from a function breaks encapsulation because basic idea of a function is to hide how the data has been received. Problem of AWS DynamoDB Docclient  is that for different data access methods (query, get, scan, put) it returns result not in direct way, but as part of an object like { Items/Item/other: <real needed data here> }

Comment: So your problem is not with promises or async/await (as your title suggested), but specifically how to design your program to work with AWS DynamoDB Docclient in a generic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I've found to be working is very simple. It's based on the fact that result of await is always converted to a resolved promise:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const items = await getItems();

    // use items
  }
  catch(err) {
    // error handling
  }
}

const getItems = async function() {
    const params = {
        TableName : "Items"
    };

    const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    return data.Items;
};

// getFeatures(), writeObjects(), putAnything() implementations
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `then` to your promise before returning it from your function and let it convert the promise result for you. Something like:

```
const getItems = function() {
    let params = {
        TableName : "Items"
    };

    return docClient.scan(params).promise()
        .then(data => data.Items);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, How about...

```
const {item, items} = await getItems()

// check which one has a value.
```

Basically one will be undefined, unfortunately i'm out at the moment so can't test it.